# Getting "The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require this" error after external program exits

Tags: vb.net

I am new to the world of .NET and have struck a problem that I can't seem to get past. Searching this forum and many others hasn't yielded a result.

I have a VB.NET program that launches an external program, then waits for the program to exit, then displays a results form.

The Results form loads some data created by the external program and presents it along with a graph. The results form has two WPF buttons (HostElements), along with labels and a graph.

I should also mention that the external program takes about 20-30 minutes to complete.

If I use the SubProcess.WaitForExit() method my program throws a "not enough quota is available to process this command" when I try to launch the results form.

In an effort to overcome this error, I have changed the program to use the Exited event to launch the form and now get "System.InvalidOperationException: 'The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require this.'" error when the results form is launched.

Relevant code snippets are below...  Any hints, suggestions, guidance greatly appreciated.

```
Public WithEvents SubProcess As New Process
Public oProg As New ProcessStartInfo

Public Sub StartAMTAS()

    oProg.FileName = "something.exe"
    oProg.Arguments = " /ar /op /ov /fv Name"

    Try
        SubProcess = Process.Start(oProg)
        SubProcess.EnableRaisingEvents = True
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Something went wrong")
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub AMTASProcess_Exited(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles SubProcess.Exited
    Results.Show()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Exited` event of a `Process` is raised on a secondary thread.  If you want to affect the UI of your app, you must do so on the UI thread.  That means that you need to marshal a method call to the UI thread and then show your form.  The simplest way to do that would be like so:

```
Invoke(Sub() Results.Show())
```

That calls the `Invoke` method of the current form.  The `Control.Invoke` method invokes a delegate on the thread that owns the handle of the control you call it on, i.e. the UI thread.  In this case, the delegate being invoked is a Lambda expression that calls the original `Results.Show` method.

If you'd like a bit more on this subject, you can [check this out](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?498387).